# Generate an absolute url in a razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like generate an absolute Url in a razor view

It might look something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register Now", "action", "controller", 
      new { area = "Area", id = @Model.Id }, null)
```

I have seen many attempts at this but have not found something that gives me the full link I need.

Comment: What is the url your trying to generate, and what route does it map to?

Comment: I will have to find that, I am using Orchard CMS and that is not at my finger tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to use `Html.ActionLink` to generate a link with an absolute URL. For example, using the `Html.ActionLink` from your question will produce the following HTML output:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register Now", "Action", "Controller", new { @area = "Area", @id = Model.Id}, null)
// output: <a href="/Area/Controller/Action/{Model.Id}">Register Now</a>
```

To generate absolute URLs, I suggest implementing a custom extension method.

```
public static string AbsoluteActionUrl(this UrlHelper url, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues)
{
    string scheme = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme;
    return url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);
}
```

Of course, you will have to write the HTML markup yourself and use the extension to generate the URL for the `href` attribute, like so:

```
<a href="@Url.AbsoluteActionUrl("Action", "Controller", new { @Area = "Area", @id = Model.Id})">Register Now</a>
```

You don't have to create the custom extension method, but then you would need to use a magic string to specify the scheme when using `Url.Action`.

The MSDN documentation for the `Url.Action` overload used above is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232(v=vs.118).aspx). There are also [other overloads available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: This looks promising, let me go try it out.